# MVC Routing for categories with spaces

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a website that has categories for the products. I wanted to have the categories defined in a route pretty much like www.domain.com/categoryA.

Here's my problem what if I have category in my database that is 'Boxing Gloves' how do I handle the space in the category name?

Comment: As Paul is hinting, it will totally work just fine. Neither ASP.NET itself nor ASP.NET Routing has any problem with spaces.

Comment: Not actually tried it but was expecting %20 to be required in the encoded url, which isn't good. Accepted the answer below to use dashes, seems like the best work-around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have spaces encoded as %20, but that doesn't really make for pretty urls. I'd suggest you convert them to dashes and disallow dashes in category names. You could also disable spaces and force users to use dashes like most tagging systems.