# How to remove white-spaces in a route in MVC5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I have an MVC5 application and inside the `RouteConfig.cs`, I have defined one route as follows:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Service",
    url: "Home/Service/{sid}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "ServiceRequestBySubcategory", sid = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Where in my case `sid` is actually the name of the subcategory. Some subcategories have single word names, which are fine, but some have names composed of two or three words, where there is a blank space between the words. The problem is that sometimes, when I press certain subcategory names, I get an error message saying that the page was not found, but if I refresh the page appears. It is quite annoying to do that. I guess this happens due to the blank space between the words. So, is there a way for me to remove the blank space between words of a subcategory names (of course if actually there are blank spaces)?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082684/mvc-routing-for-categories-with-spaces

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you URLEncode the values that could be used as {sid}

That way "foo bar" becomes "foo%20bar" and you then shouldn't run into problems with having whitespace (or any other funky character, basically) on the URL